# Looking for Bootstrap Dashboard with right-positioned navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This Bootstrap Dashboard template looks great for a project that I'm starting, but I need the navigation bar to be on the right instead of on the left.
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Is this a matter of just applying some Bootstrap property or making a slight tweak to the CSS?  I can hand-code this the hard way with CSS, but thought perhaps a Bootstrap guru has already tackled this or could point me to a shortcut.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the sidebar that is on the left side?

There are two ways to accomplish what you're asking for.

(1) Simply add the `pull-right` class (provided by bootstrap) to the sidebar.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar pull-right"></div>
```

(2) Change the order of the HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar"></div> // <===== Move me
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main"></div>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar"></div> // <===== Here I am
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used suggestion 2, and also had to transfer the offset classes from the main div to the sidebar div, ala:
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9 col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 sidebar">